# JS: istanceof check inside constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this part of code in more than one npm package:

```
function myClass (options) {
  if (!(this instanceof myClass)) return new myClass(options);
  ...
}
```

Looking at the definition of istanceof operator we have:

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

Why does it check inside the constructor if the object that I'm creating is an istanceof this class? When do I get "false"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This check is done in order to understand if the method was called via the `new` operator, or not. This way you can make different scenarios, mostly initializing static content, or returning different kind of objects.

```
function myClass (options) {
    if (!(this instanceof myClass)) 
        console.log ('not instance of');
    else
        console.log('instance of');
}

myClass('test'); // not instance of
new myClass('test'); // instance of
```

One important thing to mention - the `new` operator actually returns a new object. So

```
function MyClass(opts) {

}
var a = MyClass('a');
console.log(a); // undefined
```

And it's undefined because there is no return statement. You just execute a function and the result of it is assigned to `a`. But, if you use the `new` operator (like `var a = new MyClass('a');`), the result will be `myClass {}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way of instantiating an object:

```
var obj = new Object();
```

Whenever someone makes a mistake and forgets the new keyword, such as below:

```
var obj = Object();
```

Weird things will happen, this is why you can do typeof in the constructor, to auto-instantiate the object.
[Source](http://raganwald.com/2014/07/09/javascript-constructor-problem.html)

Comment: It's not `mistake` to forget it - it's different kind of usage :)